# Calculate Sum based on dates (Current, 7 Days,...)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following is an example of Table I am currently working with:

```
Date -------- Number -------Total 
2012-03-28     3         158                
2012-03-29     4         168              
2012-04-08     2         256            
2012-04-12     1         155.98             
2012-04-14     6         245.00             
2012-04-20     10        156              
2012-04-21     8         87      
2012-04-26     3         158                
2012-04-26     4         168              
2012-04-29     2         256            
2012-04-30     1         155.98             
2012-05-02     6         245.00             
2012-05-02     10        156              
2012-05-02     8         87
```

I need to derive a table like the following from this:

```
Total ----- Current ----7Days----14Days 
2451.96    1225.98    1869.96    1869.96
```

In This Case the Total is the SUM(Total),
Current is -7 Days from Todays Date(05/02/2013) So it adds the sum from 05/02/2013-04/25/2013
7 Days is -14 from Todays Date or -7 from the Current. So it adds the sum from 05/02/2013-04/18/2013.

So Forth. I do not know how to create a query to get the sum for 7Days.

Please Help!.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression to get the result:

```
select 
  sum(total) Total,
  sum(case when date >= dateadd(d, -7, getdate()) then total end) [Current],
  sum(case when date >= dateadd(d, -14, getdate()) then total end) [7Days],
  sum(case when date >= dateadd(d, -21, getdate()) then total end) [14Days]
from yt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ecbe/6)

If you have more date ranges, then you will add more `sum(case...)` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(Total) as 'Total',
       SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),Date,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 7,101)  
                 THEN Total ELSE 0 END) as 'Current',
       SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),Date,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 14,101)  
                 THEN Total ELSE 0 END) as '7Days' ,
       SUM( CASE WHEN convert(varchar(11),Date,101) >= convert(varchar(11),GETDATE() - 28,101)  
                 THEN Total ELSE 0 END) as '14Days' 
FROM mytable
```

**OUTPUT**

```
TOTAL   CURRENT 7DAYS   14DAYS
2451.96 1225.98 1468.98 2125.96
```